# Creating a 3D Plot In Matlab With 2 Changing Variables

Tags: matlab, for-loop, 3d, matrix, while-loop

I am trying to create a 3D plot in Matlab.

I have a very long problem starting with the data set of Y and Z.  With much manipulation it boils down to a simple y/z problem

```
y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
z=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50];


x=(y_new)/(z_new)
```

There is about 100 lines of equations manipulating y and z, to become two new variables y_new and z_new.  I would like to create a 3d plot of x,y,z.  I would want an x value for (1,5) and (1,10), (2,5), (2,10) etc.

The way I have the problem setup is only using y=1 and z=5.  I have been trying to use for-loops or while-loops for the past few hours but I am getting stuck.

If someone can help me I would appreciate the time and effort!

Comment: I don't understand where you're stuck. Is all you need an element-wise operation, i.e. `x=y_new./z_new`? Or are `y-new` and `z_new` scalars, so that you'd want `x(i)=y_new/z_new`?

Comment: Well the whole problem is done with y=1 and z=5, for example.  I get an x value.  I just am looking for a way to change y ten different times, change z different times, and get 100 values of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `for` loop. Instead, use the builtin function `meshgrid()` which is designed to solve exactly this problem.

[Here's a tutorial from 'abbe' at MIT](http://www.mit.edu/people/abbe/matlab/3d.html) which details how to create a 3D plot of a function `f(x,y)` using `meshgrid()`.

To quote the blurb:

> **3D plotting**
>
> When you make a 3-dimensional plot, you usually have a z variable that
>   is a function of both x and y. When you want x and y to vary over some
>   range, you need a matrix (rather than a vector) for x and y to get a
>   complete domain that covers all the different combinations of those x
>   and y values over some range. A function called meshgrid will set up x
>   and y matrixes like this for you. The x matrix varies the x down rows
>   and keeps it constant in columns, and the y matrix varies the y in
>   columns and keeps it constant across rows, so you get all combinations
>   of x and y if you use the two matrices.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for!  I saw this a few hours about but the article was very confusing.  The piece you posted was very clear and concise.  Thank you again!